# Multi-threading NpgsqlConnections and readers producing duplicate results. C#

Tags: npgsql

I have thousands of queries I need to run on thousands of different Schema over 10 databases. I am trying to thread these queries and use a BlockingCollection to write results into, while also using another thread to read from this collection and write it to disk as the result sets of these queries are too large to store in memory.

Here is the problem area in my code:

```
public class Node {
    public string ConnectionString;
    public string Query;

    public Node(string databaseDetails, string query) {
        //Cannot put in actual logic, but this part is fine
        ConnectionString = {logic for connection string}
        Query = "set search_path to {schema from databaseDetails};" + query
    }
}

public void runQuery(string query, BlockingCollection<Dictionary<string, object>> producer) {
        List<Node> nodes = getNodes(query);
        Parallel.ForEach(nodes, node => {
            NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(node.ConnectionString);
            conn.Open();
            NpgsqlCommand npgQuery = new NpgsqlCommand(node.Query, conn);
            NpgsqlDataReader reader = npgQuery.ExecuteReader();
            while (reader.Read()) {
                Dictionary<string, object> row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++) {
                    row[reader.GetName(i)] = reader.GetValue(i);
                }
                producer.Add(row);
            }
            conn.Close();
        });
        producer.CompleteAdding();
}
```

This code runs, and retrieves all of the results, but it duplicates a lot of the results as well, so the blocking collection has 5-10 times more records than it should. Any help would be greatly appreaciated.

Comment: It's not really possible to understand much from that code fragment - the problem could simply be coming from the allocation of queries to nodes (i.e. the getNodes method which isn't provided). I'd advise logging the queries you're executing on each node to understand who's executing what.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I was just an idiot and was comparing my generated result set to the UNION of all the queries I was running not the UNION ALL, so my "true" result set had no duplicates in it because the union was removing them :/